# unexpected number of bytes in UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage

So the problem is given an UIImage, that is then cropped using the ImageCrop class. Then when I read that cropped image into the ImagePixelHelper class it stops working correctly has the cropped image has a different amount of bytes that the expected amount.
For example, after cropping a UIImage we calculate the expected length of the image data array by doing:

- image.size.width * image.size.height * 3 for RGB
- image.size.width * image.size.height * 4 for RGBA

Then using CFDataGetBytePointer(image.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data), and checking the length of that array we find that the sizes are vastly different. Which means we dont know what format the image is in so then we cant get the pixel colour because its an unknown format.

Notes:

- ImageCrop class deals with cropping the given UIImage, with the given CGRect
- ImagePixelHelper class deals with giving the pixel colour at the given X,Y Coordinate
- Both classes are tested and work as expected standalone but break when working together

  ```
  /// Helper class for cropping images
  class ImageCrop
  {
      /// Function crops the image to the given rect and returns a new image
      ///
      /// - Parameter rect: The rect to crop to
      /// - Returns: A new image which is cropped to the rect passed in
      static func crop(image:UIImage, rect:CGRect) -> UIImage
      {
          UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
          let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

          let drawRect = CGRect(x: -rect.origin.x, y: -rect.origin.y,
                            width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)

          context?.clip(to: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                               width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height + 1))

          image.draw(in: drawRect)

          let subImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

          UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
          return subImage!
      }
  }
  ```

-

```
    /// Helper class finds pixels values within the given image
    class ImagePixelHelper
    {
        /// The image to find pixels in
        private let image: UIImage

        /// The image data
        private var data:UnsafePointer<UInt8>?

        /// The expected length of the image data
        private var expectedLengthA:Int?

        /// The expected rgb length of the image
        private var expectedLengthRGB:Int?

        /// The expected rgba length of the image
        private var expectedLengthRGBA:Int?

        /// The actual number of bytes in the image
        private var numBytes: CFIndex?

        private var pixelData: CFData?

        /// Default constructor for the ImagePixelHelper
        /// - Parameter image: The image to find pixels in
        init(image: UIImage)
        {
            self.image = image
        }

        /// Function loads all the image data for quick access later
        func loadImageData() throws
        {
            // Get the image as a CGImage
            let cgImage : CGImage = image.cgImage!

            pixelData = cgImage.dataProvider?.data

            // Get the pointer to the start of the array
            data = CFDataGetBytePtr(self.pixelData)!

            // Calculate the expected lengths
            expectedLengthA = Int(image.size.width * image.size.height)
            expectedLengthRGB = 3 * expectedLengthA!
            expectedLengthRGBA = 4 * expectedLengthA!

            // Get the length of the data
            numBytes = CFDataGetLength(pixelData)
        }

        /// Function sets all member vars to nil to help speed up GC
        func unloadImageData()
        {
            data = nil
            expectedLengthA = nil
            expectedLengthRGB = nil
            expectedLengthRGBA = nil
            numBytes = nil
        }

        /// Function gets the pixel colour from the given image using the provided x y coordinates
        /// - Parameter pixelX: The X Pixel coordinate
        /// - Parameter pixelY: The Y Pixel coordinate
        /// - Parameter bgr: Whether we should return BGR, by default this is true so must be set if you want RGB
        func getPixelValueFromImage(pixelX: Int, pixelY:Int, bgr: Bool = true) -> UIColor
        {
            // If we have all the required member vars for this operation
            if  let data = self.data,
                let expectedLengthA = self.expectedLengthA,
                let expectedLengthRGB = self.expectedLengthRGB,
                let expectedLengthRGBA = self.expectedLengthRGBA,
                let numBytes = self.numBytes
            {
                // Get the index of the pixel we want
                let index = Int(image.size.width) * pixelY + pixelX

                // Check the number of bytes
                switch numBytes
                {
                    case expectedLengthA:
                        return UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: CGFloat(data[index])/255.0)
                    case expectedLengthRGB:
                        if bgr
                        {
                            return UIColor(red: CGFloat(data[3*index+2])/255.0, green: CGFloat(data[3*index+1])/255.0, blue: CGFloat(data[3*index])/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return UIColor(red: CGFloat(data[3*index])/255.0, green: CGFloat(data[3*index+1])/255.0, blue: CGFloat(data[3*index+2])/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                        }
                    case expectedLengthRGBA:
                        if bgr
                        {
                            return UIColor(red: CGFloat(data[4*index+2])/255.0, green: CGFloat(data[4*index+1])/255.0, blue: CGFloat(data[4*index])/255.0, alpha: CGFloat(data[4*index+3])/255.0)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return UIColor(red: CGFloat(data[4*index])/255.0, green: CGFloat(data[4*index+1])/255.0, blue: CGFloat(data[4*index+2])/255.0, alpha: CGFloat(data[4*index+3])/255.0)
                        }
                    default:
                        // unsupported format
                        return UIColor.clear
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Something didnt load properly or has been destroyed
                return UIColor.clear
            }
        }
    }
```

So given the two classes above here is an example of some code run to cause the issue

```
let image = UIImage(named: "SomeImage")!

let croppedImage = ImageCrop.crop(image: image, rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

let imagePixelHelper = ImagePixelHelper(image: croppedImage)

for x in 0 ... Int(croppedImage.size.width)
{
    for y in 0 ... Int(croppedImage.size.height)
    {
        let colour = imagePixelHelper.getPixelValueFromImage(pixelX: x, pixelY: y)
        print(colour)
    }
}
```

This will print only UIColour.CLEAR as the croppedImage is an unknown format / a larger size than we expected. Then int the debugger looking at the imagePixelHelper variable the expected lengths of the data arrays are as follows for a 100*100 image:

- expectedLengthA = 10000
- expectedLengthRGB = 30000
- expectedLengthRGBA = 40000

Then the actual found length of the data array, the array of the image data is 41600 which is  larger than the expected, this is where the problem lies.
After doing a little bit of digging in the swift docs we found that we could be using the wrong type of Graphics context to crop our image, and that it suggests that instead we use UIGraphicsImageRenderer. But im struggling to find/create an implementation for cropping that works.

TLDR: In short, if an image is cropped first using the ImageCrop class, it breaks the ImagePixelHelper as the size of the image data array does not match the expected calculated size.

Comment: Your loops are wrong. The range `0 ... Int(croppedImage.size.width)` includes the upper bound, so that width+1 iterations are done. You'll want `0 ..< Int(croppedImage.size.width)`

Comment: @MartinR ok fair enough, but that doesn't actually fix the issue, this is code I wrote to paste in here, the usage is neither here nor there, the issue is the incorrect number of bytes when checking the image data

Comment: Why do you suppose the image is internally stored in raw RGB format and not PNG or JPEG?

Comment: @Sulthan because if i grab an image and run it through the code to get the colour at a certain pixel, it works perfectly fine, RGB or RGBA etc it works exactly as expected it returns the colour for the given pixel. However after cropping it using the crop code (which you can see above) the bytes count (in the get pixel colour code) show about 3 times as many bytes as i expect and not a uniform amount either so i dont know what colourspace its in or whether now my returned image is actually a PNG or what... cant seem to figure it out, hence the question

Comment: @AngryDuck The thing is that cropped image does not mean cropped data. Quoting documentation: _The resulting image retains a reference to the original image, which means you may release the original image after calling this function._. That generally means that cropped image is the same image with some properties set differently. There is no reason why there should be exactly `width` points on every row. There is a reason why `CGImage.bytesPerRow` exists.